# Как решить ошибку "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" на языке python

Tags: python

[image: Задание]

```
import math
n=1
m=18
p=1
y=1
from random import randint
x=[randint(10,40) for i in range(10)]
y=[randint(10,40) for i in range(10)]
def F_l1():
   global l1
   l1=0
   for i in range(10):
       l1+=x[i]-1
       return l1
F_l1()
print('l1= ', l1)
def F_l2():
   global z
   for i in range(10):
       if m>5*l1 and x[i]>5:
           z=x[i]+y[i]
       elif x[i] and n<10:
           z=x[i]-y[i]       
       else:
           z=x[i]*y[i]
   return z
F_l2()
print('Массив z=',z)
for i in range(10): 
    while n<=10:
       p=((z)/(x[i]+y[i]))**2
       n=n+1
       y*=p      
c=p**(1/3)
y=c*m
print('Произведение функции Z =',y )
```

[image: То как выглядит сама ошибка]

Comment: y*=int(p)  
-> p - у Вас float

Comment: p=((z)/(x[i]+y[i]))**2
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: n=0 while n<10:    Списки с 0 индекса начинаются

Comment: та самая же ошибка(

Comment: y - список, а вы его умножаете на число. Если бы оно было целым, список бы расширился, а так справедливо выдает ошибку: `y=[randint(10,40) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: Кстати, тот у, кторрый у=1, я не понимаю, как в используете

Comment: Боже точно, спасибо большое))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте немного приберемся в вашем коде. Мне кажется, как-то так надо считать

```
from random import randint

x = [randint(10, 40) for _ in range(10)]
y = [randint(10, 40) for _ in range(10)]
m = randint(10, 100)

l1 = sum(x) - 10
print('l1= ', l1)

z = []
for i in range(10):
    if m > 5*l1 and abs(x[i]) > 5:
        z.append(x[i] + y[i])
    elif abs(x[i]) > 5 and i < 9:
        z.append(x[i] - y[i])
    else:
        z.append(x[i] * y[i])
print('z=', z)

p = 1
for i in range(10):
    p *= (z[i]/(x[i] + y[i]))**2
Z = m * p**(1/3)
print('Z =', Z)
```

Comment: Вау, как коротко и круто вышло

Comment: только вы проверьте, я писал из головы. Мог ошибиться

Comment: все отлично работает